# R: Custom equation on ggplot. stat_function with a third variable

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to introduce a custom equation to my ggplot.

```
data1989 %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = daysAFTERFIRE, y = NDVI)) + 
 stat_function(fun= ~ (.meanNDVI)-(exp(-0.0000348*(.x)-2.17)))
```

As you see, my custom equation includes both `y` (column `NDVI`) and `x` (column `daysAFTERFIRE`), but also a third term, `meanNDVI` which is another column on my tibble.

Trying to run I get this:

```
Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
object '.meanNDVI' not found
```

Anyone has any idea to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your function outside of the `ggplot` call, and then it might be easier to troubleshoot:

Assign your column containing a repeating mean value to a numeric variable:

```
meanNDVI_variable <- df$meanNDVI[1]
```

Then use it in your function:

```
f <- function(.x) (meanNDVI_variable)-(exp(-0.0000348*(.x)-2.17)))
```

Then:

```
data1989 %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = daysAFTERFIRE, y = NDVI)) + 
 stat_function(fun= f)))
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem, I keep having the same error. Apparently it doesn't know where to look for meanNDVI

Comment: Is `meanNDVI` in a dataframe? Have you tried using `df$meanNDVI`?

Comment: Nope! As I mention in my post, it's another column of the tibble. So if I write: `f <- function(.x) (data1989$meanNDVI)-(exp(-0.0000348*(.x)-2.17))` as you suggest I get `Warning messages:
Warning messages:
1: In (data1989$meanNDVI) - (exp(-3.48e-05 * (.x) - 2.17)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
Elements must equal the number of rows or 1`

Comment: Is`meanNDVI`  the same number, since it's a calculated mean? If so, you can assign the value to a variable, instead of a value in a dataframe: `meanNVDI_variable <- df$meanNDVI[1]` and then replace `meanNVDI` with `meanNVDI_variable` in your function.